copying data from clickhouse to oracle with clickhouse-jdbc-bridge
Very strange situation. I use simple schema of copying.
In source table 1857428 rows, after copying in oracle in target table 3132400 rows.

Oracle: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit
Clickhouse:24.1.4.20
clickhouse_jdbc-bridge : clickhouse-jdbc-bridge-2.1.0-1
datasource config:
/etc/clickhouse-jdbc-bridge/config/datasources/ora.json

{
"$schema": "/etc/clickhouse-jdbc-bridge/config/datasource.jschema",
  "ora": {
  "driverUrls": [
    "/u01/drivers/ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar"
  ],
  "connectionTestQuery": "select 1 from dual",
  "driverClassName": "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver",
  "jdbcUrl": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//1.2.3.4:1521/nsser",
  "username": "usr",
  "password": "pwd",
  "maximumPoolSize": 20,
  "MaxLifetime": 720000
  }
}


In clickhouse I have tables:
CREATE TABLE mac.ch_cfc_str
(
    id_contract Int64,
    lot_id         Int64,
    doc_num        FixedString(19),--String,
    customer       Int64,
    sign_date      DateTime,
    sign_number    FixedString(100),--String,
    version        Int64,
    type_info      Int64,
    date_cache     Int64,
    datecalc_cache Int64
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
ORDER BY (datecalc_cache, date_cache, type_info) ---- м.б. doc_num сюда
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192;

With data:
1 857 428 rows.
select sum(1) from mac.ch_cfc_str;


CREATE TABLE mac.ora_cfc(
  sign_date      DateTime,
  sign_number    String,
  doc_num        String,
  datecalc_cache Decimal(10,4),
  date_cache     Decimal(10,4),
  type_info      Decimal(10,4),
  version        Decimal(10,4)
)
ENGINE JDBC('ora','mac','ora_cfc');

In oracle table
create table mac.ora_cfc
(
  sign_date      date not null,
  sign_number    varchar2(256) not null,
  doc_num        varchar2(256) not null,
  datecalc_cache number not null,
  date_cache     number not null,
  type_info      number not null,
  version        number not null
);

And copying do with call in clickhouse
insert into mac.ora_cfc(sign_date,sign_number,doc_num,datecalc_cache,date_cache,type_info,version)
                select sign_date,sign_number,doc_num,datecalc_cache,date_cache,type_info,version 
                  from mac.ch_cfc_str

After 20-30 seconds copying finiched and in oracle table I see 3132400 rows
select sum(1) from mac.ora_cfc;

It's very strange, I sure that I am single user of this tables.
Sometimes copying freeze or not begining, sometimes copy jyst a part of rows.
Sometime strage errors:
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("mac"."ora_cfc"."DOC_NUM")
ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
HTTP status code: 500 Internal Server Error, body: Invalid LEB128 sequence.
HTTP status code: 500 Internal Server Error, body: index: 173050309, length: 136620051 

I know that if I remove both String fields then copying success or when I stay only String columns.
Any help please.

I know data, there are no null values.```1857428
select sum(1) from mac.ch_cfc_str;
0
select sum(1) from mac.ch_cfc_str where doc_num is null;```

DOC_NUM is defined as not null and hence the error ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("mac"."ora_cfc"."DOC_NUM")
ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column occurs when you're trying to insert or update a LONG datatype value into a column that is not defined as LONG
The version field in source is decimal and on Oracle is number.
Check if any of the Decimal fields on the Source is null and you are trying to insert into Oracle number fields which are not null
